# Get the most recent records on date and id field mySql

Tags: mysql, inner-join, coalesce

I have a table like this:

```
+--------+--------+------+----------+----+----+
| id     | id2    | id3  | date     |at1 | at2|
+--------+--------+------+----------+----+----+
| 111    |        |      | 5/12/19  | a  |    |
| 111    |  10    |      | 2/12/19  | b  |  j |
| 111    |  10    | 45   | 2/12/19  | f  |    |
| 111    |  10    | 45   | 3/12/19  | c  |    |
| 222    |  1010  |      | 5/12/19  |    | e  |
| 222    |  1010  |  56  | 1/12/19  |a   | d  |
| 33     |  1010  |  56  | 5/12/19  |    | c  |
+---------------------------------------------+
```

I would like to retrieve the most recent records based on `date` and `id` and expose only the rows that has the combination `id` and (`id2` or `id3`). In the table I provided the outcome should be like this:

```
+--------+--------+------+----------+----+----+
| id     | id2    | id3  | date     |at1 | at2|
+--------+--------+------+----------+----+----+
| 111    |  10    |      | 2/12/19  | b  |  j |
| 111    |  10    | 45   | 3/12/19  | c  | a  |
| 222    |  1010  |      | 5/12/19  |a   | e  |
| 222    |  1010  |  56  | 1/12/19  |a   | e  |
| 33     |  1010  |  56  | 5/12/19  |    | c  |
+---------------------------------------------+
```

I tried to implement it using this query (from another question) but I did not manage as I am not quite familiar with sql:

```
select t.id, t.id2, t.id3, t.date,
  coalesce(t.at1, g.at1) at1, coalesce(t.at2, g.at2) at2
from tab t inner join (
  select id, id2, id3,
    max(date) date, max(at1) at1, max(at2) at2
  from tab  
  group by id2, id3  
) g on g.pm = t.pm and g.pm2 <=> t.pm2 and g.pm3 <=> t.pm3 and g.date = t.date
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: *"I would like to retrieve the most recent records based on date and id"*  Not possible atleast not with this dataset the combination of date and id columns is non deterministic ...  Consider  this table and data `row_id|id|date` with `1|1|2019-10-21` and `2|1|2019-10-21` and you need sort on `date, id` yourself which of those records would you put first and which one second if need to sort on `date, id, row_id` it become much more clear what to do..

Comment: Why isn't `222, 1010, NULL` present in expected output @michael?

Comment: @SalmanA Nice catch, thanks.

Comment: @RaymondNijland I am not quite sure if I understood what you mean. To make it more clear, those ids represent different levels of information: `id` is the primary level. Different `id2` can point to the same `id` as well as `id3` for `id2`.

Comment: *" I am not quite sure if I understood what you mean."* i am not quite sure how to explain it more easy what i meant ...

Comment: The way I see it: if `row_id` is the equivalent of the `id` in my case, then they are two different records. If `row_id` is just the id of the row then it's a duplicate.

Comment: no row_id is the equivalent of `PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT` .. that makes the combination deterministic which makes the sort deterministic (predicate) your data combination of date and id is non deterministic (random) when you sort you get non deterministic (unpredicate) results.

Comment: I see now - thanks

Comment: *"SalmanA Nice catch, thanks."* Also the query off @SalmanA should not solve that non deterministic data issue by the way...

Comment: @raymond what seems to be the problem? If two dates qualify as most recent it'll return both. There needs to be tie in dates to begin with. If there ***IS*** an issuem, it could easily be solved by adding a check for id column. Stop complicating things.